# Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

inside test file I want to check results after action

```
ctrl.send('createLoanApplication').then(function(){
  console.log('test');       
});
```

this is action

```
createLoanApplication: function () {
  var value = this.get('selectedCompany');
  if (value) {
    var controller = this;
    return  $.post('/api/loanapplication/create/' + value).done(function (data) {
      controller.transitionToRoute('loan-details', data.id);                  
    });                
  }              
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`send` does not return a value. Therefore you cannot take a `then` of its result.

Comment: how can i get promise from action?

Comment: i want to test action which return promise.

Comment: You can't. The action doesn't return a promise or anything else.

Comment: are you sure? This is main part of my application. also routing and just for it need test :D

Comment: Read the source code at https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.6.1/packages_es6/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/action_handler.js#L177.